# save button error in AS project

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, mxml, mxmlc

Whats wrong with the following code,There is an error at 
                 saveButton.visible = false;
        discardButton.visible = false;

```
package
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.media.Camera;
import flash.media.Video;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.FileReference;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import com.adobe.images.JPGEncoder;

public class caml extends Sprite
{
    private var camera:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
    private var video:Video = new Video();
    private var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(320,240);
    private var bmp:Bitmap;
    private var fileReference:FileReference = new FileReference();
    private var byteArray:ByteArray;
    private var jpg:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder();

    public function caml()
    {
        saveButton.visible = false;
        discardButton.visible = false;

        saveButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, saveImage);
        discardButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, discard);
        capture.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, captureImage);

        if (camera != null)
        {
            video.smoothing = true;
            video.attachCamera(camera);
            video.x = 140;
            video.y = 40;
            addChild(video);
        }
        else
        {
            trace("No Camera Detected");
        }
    }
        private function captureImage(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            bmd.draw(video);
            bmp = new Bitmap(bmd);
            bmp.x = 140;
            bmp.y = 40;
            addChild(bmp);

            capture.visible = false;
            saveButton.visible = true;
            discardButton.visible = true;
        }

        private function saveImage(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            byteArray = jpg.encode(bmd);
            fileReference.save(byteArray, "Image.jpg");
            removeChild(bmp);
            saveButton.visible = false;
            discardButton.visible = false;
            capture.visible = true;
        }

        private function discard(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            removeChild(bmp);
            saveButton.visible = false;
            discardButton.visible = false;
            capture.visible = true;
        }


}
}
```

Comment: as far as I can tell from this code (if it's not partial) then saveButton and discardButton would be null at the point you are getting there.

you have no initialization of those variables.

Comment: I thought of the same and how to attach the button to the button event

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a document root class and the buttons is added to stage in the flash fla file. In that case you need to add the buttons to your declaration as public members:

```
public var saveButton : Button;
public var discardButton : Button;
```

---

**UPDATE**

I never use the flash components myself but you might find an answer here on how to use Flash components in Flashbuilder:
http://www.moock.org/blog/archives/000253.html
http://www.ruttencutter.com/?p=20

Comment: And how do you import the Button.Its a AS project

Comment: import fl.controls.Button; (make sure the component is added to your stage or assets library before compiling, otherwise it won't work).